# Add Case=False to my code when creating a new variable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add `Case=False` to the code below so the `NON_COV_RFV` would flag both 'Seizure' and 'seizure' but am getting an error. Is it possible to add a case=False? I know this can be done in str.contains but there are data in my `REASON_FOR_VISIT` field, for example `seizure, fever`, and I would not want to flag that as `NON_COV_RFV`.

I want to avoid having to write another line of code for "seizure". If it were for just this occurrence it would be fine to add a second line but I have many variables for `REASON_FOR_VISIT` and that is why I would like to figure out if I can plug in a `case=False` expression.

```
COV_RFV.loc[COV_RFV['REASON_FOR_VISIT'] == 'Seizure', case=False, 'NON_COV_RFV'] = 1
```

ERROR:

```
COV_RFV.loc[COV_RFV['REASON_FOR_VISIT'] == 'Seizure', case=False, 'NON_COV_RFV'] = 1
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, but you could use this workaround:

```
COV_RFV.loc[COV_RFV['REASON_FOR_VISIT'].str.lower() == 'seizure', 'NON_COV_RFV'] = 1
```

or

```
COV_RFV.loc[COV_RFV['REASON_FOR_VISIT'].str.match('Seizure', case=False), 'NON_COV_RFV'] = 1
```